# Import local site to Wordpress.com

Tags: wordpress.com-hosting

There are many questions about the opposite of this question: import from server to local, but it's not the same, so please do not mark as duplicate.

I have installed WordPress with MAMP. After modifying the php and css files, I have my website.

Now I am trying to upload it to Wordpress.com so it's live. It's a test for university, so no need to have a fancy domain, the free one is enough for me.

I have tried:

1. Import local press (.xml file)
2. On WordPress.com, go to import and import that file
3. It imports successfully. But then nothing changes. I don't see the media, or the page I created locally.

Any help?

Comment: Regina, this stack is for Q&A of Wordpress.org self-hosted applications.  It is not for Wordpress.com.  If you're looking for support with the .com SAAS you need to be in touch with their support directly.

Comment: "free one is enough for me" If you're modifying PHP files, no it's not. The free version of WordPress.com does not allow you to upload PHP files. Exporting an XML file will not include PHP or CSS changes anyway. What files have you been modifying?

Comment: I got in touch with support and this is not possible. I just switched to Firebase and did it in 5 minutes. Free as well. Thanks for the input, though.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to put up a temporary, or development, or staging site is to use [poopy.life](http://poopy.life).
It's a free site on which you can set up a WordPress install and use it for demo or testing, etc. It's a "wordpress.org" type install, not a .com install. I believe the site disappears after a short period of time (days? week?) if not used, but I think its lifetime can be extended.  It sounds like it would have been a good alternative for you.

There may be a few other sites offering similar services.

I have used it successfully a few times.